# Playlists design for a music streaming app

Tags: mysql, database-design

So we have the following tables for a music streaming app,

```
Table tracks
----
id
name
album
artist

Table album
----
id
name

Table artist
----
id
name
```

Now, each user is given a feature to create playlists. Hence, a song can be part of multiple playlists belonging to the same user and other users as well. How do I design that part? The closest I have come to is

```
Table users
----
id
email

Table playlists
----
id
name
by_user
```

And then create a table for each playlists with the songs included in them.

```
Table playlist_1
----
track_no
track_name

Table playlist_2
----
track_no
track_name

Table playlist_n (technically incorrect, but you might understand)
----
track_no
track_name
```

The *1,2...n* in the above table names is the value from playlist.id. The problem with this method is that if there are 100,000 playlists created, 100,000 tables are created, which is sort of not the right way I feel.

Comment: "which is sort of not the right way I feel." Not only "sort of" but totally. Essentially all you need is one table with the playlist ID, the track ID and the number of the track in the list. If and only if a track is in a playlist a record in that table exists, with the track's ID and the playlist's ID.

Comment: So, the solution is to have two tables, viz, **table playlists with id, name and by_user** and **another table with playlists.id, tracks.id and sl_no**. The sl_no corresponds to the track no of the song in the corresponding playlist. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Not sure if I get your comment right. So let me rephrase: One table for the playlists, with the ID of the user the list belongs to and optionally other attributes, such as a name for the playlist. And one table assigning tracks to playlists, with the playlist ID and the track ID and the position of the track in the playlist. But as you already have the table for the playlists in your description, I only count one extra table (minus your _n_ tables for each playlist if you want to count them).

Comment: We both are on the same page. I wish I could accept your comment as the answer, but I can't since it is a comment. :D Thanks a lot though.

Comment: Do **not** have one table per playlist.  Period.  Full stop.  If you want to discuss things further, start a new Question and include tentative `CREATE TABLE` and `SELECTs`.